# Split a string contain dash and minus sign

Tags: java, regex

I have to split a string which contain dash character and minus sign.
I tried to split based on the unicode character (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyphen#Unicode), still it considering minus sign same as dash character. How van I solve it?

Expected output

(coun)

(US)

-1

Actual output

(coun)

(US)

// actually blank line will print here but SO editor squeezing the blank line

1

```
 public static void main(String[] args)  {
        char dash = '\u002D';
        int i = -1;
       String a = "(country)" + dash + "(US)" + dash + i;
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\u002D", Pattern.LITERAL);
        String[] m = p.split(a);
        for (String s : m) {
            System.out.println(s);
        }
    }
```

I guess some conversion happens during the string concatenation but not sure. 
 Any suggestion to solve this issue is welcome

Comment: `\u002D`  is ASCII hyphen and same is also present in `-1` hence `split` method is giving you back `1`

Comment: @anubhava No, U+2212 ist a mathematical minus. A hyphen is U+002D and completely different.

Comment: That's what I am saying these are different :) Since `U+002D` is also present in `-1` hence `split` method will split on that aslo

Comment: @anubhava  Thanks. you are partially right.  I was using the wrong unicode. I should have used U+2010

Comment: Use `\u2010` will also work fine.

Answer (score 0):

The operation `dash + i` is evaluated as numeric addition.
I think your string should be

`String a = "(country)" + dash + "(US)" + dash + "" + i`;

to produce the output you described.

Answer (score 0):

@anubhava was partially right, I was using the wrong unicode.
I should have used "\u2010". Now everything working as expected.

```
  public static void main(String[] args)  {
        char dash = '\u2010';
        int i = -1;
        char dashesd = '-';
        String a = "(coun)"+dash+"(US)"+dash+i;
        System.out.println(a);
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\u2010", Pattern.LITERAL);
       String [] m=  p.split(a);
        for (String s : m) {
            System.out.println(s);
        }
```