# Split a string contain hyphen and minus sign

Tags: java, regex

This question is similar to my previous question [Split a string contain dash and minus sign](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48744913/split-a-string-contain-dash-and-minus-sign). But I asked it in a wrong and then it got a slightly different semantics and people answered(including) in that perspective. Therefore rather than modifying that question I thought it's better to ask in a new question.

I have to split a string which contain hyphen-minus character and minus sign. I tried to split based on the unicode character (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyphen#Unicode), still it considering minus sign same as hyphen-minus character. Is there a way I can solve it?

Expected output

(coun)

(US)

-1

Actual output

(coun)

(US)

// actually blank line will print here but SO editor squeezing the blank line

1

```
public static void main(String[] args)  {
        char dash = '-';
        int i = -1;
       String a = "(country)" + dash + "(US)" + dash + i;
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("-", Pattern.LITERAL);
        String[] m = p.split(a);
        for (String s : m) {
            System.out.println(s);
        }
    }
```

Comment: try using - sign not followed by a number, e.g: Pattern.compile('-[^0-9]')

Comment: `-` and `\u002D` are actually the exact same characters. So you can't distinguish between them. So either use a different separation character if your data contains a minus, or split with a fixed number of fields only (this only works if only the last field can contain a minus).

Comment: to avoid the confusion I changed unicode value to character

Comment: I think minus sign unicode(U+2212 − MINUS SIGN) different than hyphen-minus unicode according to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyphen#Unicode. But java split not able to distinguish between these 2

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt, he does, but he expected that Java's `Integer.toString` did not. Unfortunately (or not), Java uses `\u002d` as a minus sign, not the `\u2212`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
char dash = '\u2010'; // 2010 is hyphen, 002D is hyphen-minus
int i = -1;
String a = "(country)" + dash + "(US)" + dash + i;
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\u2010", Pattern.LITERAL);
String[] m = p.split(a);
for (String s : m) {
    System.out.println(s);
}
```

The string representation of an integer always uses the hyphen-minus as the negative sign:

From [`Integer.toString`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#toString(int,%20int)):

> If the first argument is negative, the first element of the result is the ASCII minus character '-' ('\u002D'). If the first argument is not negative, no sign character appears in the result.

so in the end your string has 3 hyphen-minus characters. That's why `split` can't distinguish between them.

Since you can't change the string representation of an integer, you need to change the `dash` variable to store a hyphen instead of hyphen-minus. Now there are 2 hyphens and 1 hyphen-minus in your string, making `split` able to distinguish between them.

Comment: Is there a java documentation for this statement "The string representation of an integer always uses the hyphen-minus as the negative sign" ?